# Setup Laravel 5.4 to use React

Tags: laravel, reactjs, webpack, gulp

I am not new to Laravel but am new to JavaScript frameworks.

I want to use React in a laravel build but cannot find any information on how to do this.

I have Laravel 5.4. I know this comes pre-packed with Vue and Laravel Mix instead of Gulp.

I am following the tutorial here: https://blog.tighten.co/adding-react-components-to-a-laravel-app but this is not meant for 5.4. It mentions needing to update the gulpfile but, since Laravel 5.4 doesn't use Gulp, there isn't one!

Can someone please help with a small tutorial or a couple of steps that I need to replicate in order to get React working in 5.4?

I have Googled but can only find NPM links, which are less than useful!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks to Joe for pointing out the part of the docs that I needed. There was a little more to it so will describe my steps below to help anyone else out.

1. Delete the `node_modules` folder. This isn't necessary for brand new builds but if you have followed any other tutorials and installed things you don't need, this will save a few headaches. If you don't have a `node_modules` folder, ignore this step.

   **Please note** that the above step will remove anything you have installed using NPM.
2. Run `npm install` from your project root. This will install all NPM components used by Laravel.
3. Open `webpack.mix.js` and change:

   ```
   mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js') 
       .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
   ```

   to

   ```
   mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
       .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
   ```
4. Run `npm run dev` to compile the Javascript from the lesson contained in the question above. Your React JS outputs should now be working.
5. (optional) Use `npm run watch` to compile on the fly.

I really hope this helps someone else out as much as it helped me!

Comment: Make sure you remove the unnecessary dependencies from your `package.json` too - otherwise `npm install` is just going to put all the junk you got rid of back in there :p

Answer (score 5):

[According to the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#react), React support is built in to Mix:

> Mix can automatically install the Babel plug-ins necessary for React support. To get started, replace your mix.js() call with mix.react():

```
mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.jsx', 'public/js');
```

> Behind the scenes, Mix will download and include the appropriate babel-preset-react Babel plug-in.

I'm not 100% sure whether or not this'll automatically include React in your output bundle - my guess would be no (in which case you'll have to use a normal `mix.js()` call to pull it in).

Comment: Thanks Joe. There was a little more required but I will post in my own answer so that others looking my find what they need.

Comment: @Wildcard27: Yeah, I'm not that familiar with Laravel, so I figured my answer might not have the full details. Glad you were able to sort it :)

Comment: To be honest, I only skimmed over the docs as I read somewhere that Laraval only has support for Vue. I wish I could find where as it needs to be corrected!