# Is there any way to incorperate react with into an existing laravel 5.2 application?

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, laravel-5

I have an application built out in Laravel 5.2 with a mySQL DB, I'm trying to find a way to integrate React as the frontend framework with the version of Laravel I currently have. Is this possible?

Comment: This link in for 5.4 but it may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43228233/setup-laravel-5-4-to-use-react

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You can find more information in the official react docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-react-in-one-minute

Answer (score 0):

Definitively possible. You would be creating 2 apps: React for the front end and PHP/Laravel as an API for the data that your react app uses.

Comment: What if the laravel app is already a full fledged working application with the whole MVC model working already. Is there anyway to incorporate it so that I don't need to host it separately?

Comment: A react build file is just 1 HTML page, 1 CSS bundle file and 1 javascript file, plus any extra images you added. It can be hosted on any web server. You can setup your server to serve your React app from port 80 and your API from another port